# How to change the color of table cells based on a string?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want my table row to change its color depending its dropdown status. How to do this using ajax?

```
echo '<table id="table_id">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>'.$client.'</b></td>';
echo '<td>
<select class="color_status" onchange="update_Status(this.value)">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

If I will select a red in the dropdown the current row cell will change its color.
I did something like this on script:

```
function update_Status(str){
     if(str=='Red'){
       //the current row cells will turn to red
     }
     if(str=='Green'){
       //the current row cells will turn to green
     }
     if(str=='Yellow'){
       //the current row cells will turn to yellow
     }
}
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Do you need change to be applied instanly by the means of javascript or is it ok to reload page and get updated result?

Comment: hmmm. just want to applied instantly withoud loading the page. like an ajax behaviour.

Comment: fyi you didnt close your select's class. should be class="color_status"

Comment: I just forgot to put that when I created the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little simplistic and may need to be updated for your specific application but given the sample code you have shown this seems to work.

You can look for the parent node of the dropdown and then get the sibling `td` and change it `backgroundColor` using the element value directly. You do need to pass the element instead of just the value `update_Status(this)` instead of `update_Status(this.value)` as you need to find the parent and sibling starting from the element.

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<table id="table_id">
    <tr>
        <td><b>'.$client.'</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="color_status" onchange="update_Status(this)">
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Green">Green</option>
                <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will do what you need I think:

```
function update_Status(list) {
    var cell = list.parentNode;

    var targetCell = cell;

    do targetCell = targetCell.previousSibling;
    while (targetCell && targetCell.nodeType != 1);

    targetCell.style.backgroundColor = list.value;
}

// I'm assuming if you got many rows with this dropdown you would need to iterate through result of getElementsByClassName to execute onchange on each one.
document.getElementsByClassName('color_status')[0].onchange();
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LxL77/) - Find sibling `td` and change `backgroundColor`

---

---

[**Multi-Row DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvWnk/)

---

> Currently some browser engines insert TextNodes for white spaces,
>   therefore previousSibling may not actually return the `td` the first
>   time it is called.
>   TextNodes are of type 3 and you want to make sure
>   your finding a ElementNode, which is type 1.
>   That is why we loop
>   until previousSibling returns a node type 1

Comment: @jarich: Has this helped you solve your problem or are you still stuck? If you could leave some feedback that would be nice to indicate to future users, looking to solve similar issues, if this or something else has worked for you.